# How are you supposed to handle the changes to a dynamic list in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So lets say I have a view that delivers the list property `UserContext.ServicesList` to the controller. The user probably already has an existing list, and we would like to update the changed records to that list. What is the best approach to:

1) Delete records that were removed from the list?

2) Update existing records?

3) Add new records?

Thanks!

**Example classes**:

```
public class UserPage
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string AboutMe { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string AvailableTime { get; set; }

    public List<Services> ServicesList { get; set; }

}

public class Services
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

**Example controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserPage UserContext)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (UserContext.ServicesList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in UserContext.ServicesList)
            {
                // What do I do here?
            }
        }
        db.Entry(UserContext).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();   
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(UserContext);
}
```

Comment: If the `ServiceId` value of `0`, then its new, so add, otherwise update (or delete, but what property identifies its been deleted?). Based on your previous (now deleted) question, you were handling the delete event in the view which suggests you should have been removing the item from the database using ajax

Comment: @StephenMuecke No property, it's just gone from the list on post. You know of a better way to identify a delete?

Comment: Use a view model with a `IsDeleted` property, and in the view, generate a hidden input for it. Then when you click the associated 'Delete' link, change its value to `"True"` (and hide the row but do not remove it from the DOM. Alternatively change the sign of the `ServiceId` property (i.e. if it was 5, then make it -5). Then you have an indication in the post method if it should be deleted.

Comment: And what is property `Id`? Is that the relationship to `UserPage`? (in which case it should be named `UserPageId` or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would delete all the records of `ServiceList` and then add the records anew that comes from the form post like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserPage UserContext,int id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (UserContext.ServicesList != null)
        {
            var dbList = db.Services.Where(x=>x.User.Id == id);
            foreach(var item in dbList){
              db.Services.Remove(item)
            }
            foreach (var item in UserContext.ServicesList)
            {
                db.Services.Add(item);
            }
        }
        db.Entry(UserContext).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();   
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(UserContext);
}
```

It just keeps the things simple. Otherwise, you have to compare every time, how many records were deleted, how many are new and how many are new. Easy and simple way is to delete the old list and add it again. I have observed this pattern not only in EF but also in plain ADO.Net

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the existing records. So simply you can delete the removed one & Add new.

```
foreach (var item in UserContext.ServicesList)
{
    if(item.ServiceId == exists)
    {
        //Check the values & Update if needed else leave
    }
    else
    { 
        //Remove or Add
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, but how do you determine if an entry is added or deleted?

Comment: you need to check the UserContext.ServicesList record with the database right??